# How to read a JSON file stored in classpath resource in Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm a novice to Spring WebFlux. I want to read a JSON file stored in `classpath resource` and convert to a POJO class. The folder structure is `resources/defaults/myjson.json`. I'm using Jackson for conversion. Upon reading, this will get converted to `MyJson.java`. As of now, I'm doing the below approach.

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private MyJson myJson;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.myJson = MyFileUtils.readFile(objectMapper, "classpath:/defaults/myjson.json", MyJson.class);
    }

    public MyJson getMyJson() {
        return this.myJson;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use **ObjectMapper**

```
Pojo pojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new ClassPathResource("./defaults/myjson.json").getFile(), Pojo.class);
```

Here Pojo define your pojo class.

Comment: Okay. Now I have a doubt. This is a blocking IO, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah this is blocking IO.

Comment: You can modify this code to support non blocking io by creating a separate thread and sent this task to that.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this question and thanks to gnana jeyam95 whose answer helped me.

I would like to answer to you about the fact that this would be a blocking IO (I don't know by myself if that's true or not).

Maybe, if that's a problem, you could load the POJO once for all, during application startup, and then always clone the loaded POJO (with SerializationUtils for instance) so that you won't need to read the JSON file anymore once the application's startup has finished.

I did something like this in my project:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Service
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
    private Pojo pojo;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        try {
            pojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new ClassPathResource("pojo.json").getFile(), Pojo.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log error
        }
    }

    public void myMethodNeedingPojoFromJson() {
        // Do stuff
        Pojo methodPojo = SerializationUtils.clone(pojo);
        // Do other stuff
    }
}
```

However, I don't know if this optimization is a good idea or not.
Also, there may be a more elegant way to do so... Any comment would be appreciated. ^_^

Comment: No cloning would be required. As said by gnana jeyam95 and the way that I already did (which is in question), is more than enough. That will make the application non-blocking.