# How to read files from the sub folder of resource folder

Tags: java, spring-boot

How to read files from the sub folder of resource folder.

I have some json file in resources folder like :

```
src 
    main
        resources 
            jsonData
                d1.json
                d2.json
                d3.json
```

Now I want to read this in my class  which is

```
src 
    main
        java
            com
                myFile
                    classes
```

here is what I am trying but getting failed.

```
File folder = new File("./src/main/java/resources/jsonData/");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
               // my operation of Data.
            }
        }
```

Not working then I am trying :

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("classpath:jsonData/data1.json");
File folder = new File(resource.getURI());
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

both of things are not working.

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392706/how-to-read-a-json-file-stored-in-classpath-resource-in-spring-webflux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using `getClass.GetResource()`

`File[] fileList = (new File(getClass().getResource("/exampleFolder").toURI())).listFiles();`

Comment: Magouls but this is getting faile when i make jar

Comment: It's a little more tricky with jars sometimes. Here is a link to a few options on how to do it.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247669/read-directory-inside-jar-with-inputstreamreader)